# Posting a Blob of a .jpg or .png works but posting a Blob of a .psd does not work why?

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

See the solution at the bottom.

So I obtain a Blob of a .jpg or .png and it stores it on the server I obtain a blob of a psd and it does nothing shows an error the error is "aborted" in firebug. Why does this happen?

Note this works on localhost, but not on live server.

```
var xxx = 0;
    function upload(blobOrFile) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");
      xhr.open('POST', 'fileupload.php', true);
      xhr.onload = function(e) {};
      xhr.setRequestHeader ("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
      xhr.send(blobOrFile);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function(a) {
           //alert("In upload()");
              if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
                xxx = 0;
              }
              if(xhr.readyState == 0 || xhr.readyState == 1 || xhr.readyState == 2 || xhr.readyState == 3) {
                xxx = 1;
              }

      };
    }

    $(document).on("change", "#userfile", (function(f){
          var blob = this.files[0];

          upload(blob);



    }));
```

The Form

```
<form action="fileupload.php" method="POST" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>" name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>">
    <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile"><br>
    <input type="button" id="but" value="Start Upload">
</form>
```

The file the js xhr posts to

```
<?php
    var_dump($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
    $a = fopen("a.psd", "a+b");
    fwrite($a,$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
    var_dump($_POST);
    var_dump($_FILES);
    fclose($a);
    exit();
?>
```

The Solution
The file was being rejected due the server accepting only certain content types.

```
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append( 'file', blobOrFile);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");
      xhr.open('POST', 'fileupload.php', true);
      xhr.onload = function(e) {};
      xhr.setRequestHeader ("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
      xhr.send(fd);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function(a) {
           //alert("In upload()");
              if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
                xxx = 0;
              }
              if(xhr.readyState == 0 || xhr.readyState == 1 || xhr.readyState == 2 || xhr.readyState == 3) {
                xxx = 1;
              }

      };
```

This is pre-pended to the file when sent using the FormData api.

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="a.psd"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Comment: Post the error, if you please.

Comment: did you check settings like `post_max_size` or `upload_max_filesize`?

Comment: @mishu post_max_size 8M, upload_max_filesize 2M, file size trying to post 1008kb

Comment: @EricHauenstein there is no error in the PHP logs

Comment: If one file does get saved it must be some configuration issue.. maybe it takes too long, longer than `max_execution_time`..

Comment: @mishu max_execution_time 30, it seams to work fine on a local server but not on a live server..

Comment: It may be that `xhr.overrideMimeType` is manipulating the data in the psd blob and you get unexpected results. This may work for jpeg, but not for psd.

Comment: @DavidDomain I have tried removing xhr.overrideMimeType and it does the same thing. If I upload a excel .xlsx file I get an error "NetworkError: 403 Forbidden

Comment: Wait, am i missing something? Where are you actually creating the blob?
`blob` is just a file from the file input list right?